# covert a table definition class from SQLAlchemy into vanilla MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to read in a database dump, but I must have the schema defined to do so.

Unfortunately (?), the schema was built using SQLAlchemy. The table definitions are implemented as such:

```
class Customer(Base):
    """Sqlalchemy model."""
    __tablename__ = "customer"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)

    name = Column('name', String(64), nullable=False)
    given_name = Column('given_name', String(32), nullable=True)
    family_name = Column('family_name', String(32), nullable=True)
```

etc etc.

Is there any way to easily convert this back into a MySQL table definition?   I can't find anything that would do so.  I would like to be able to do this in a scaleable manner, and not type it all by hand each time I have to do a database migration.  I'm also suspecting that I'm not the first person to ever have tried this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/metadata_schema.html#how-can-i-get-the-create-table-drop-table-output-as-a-string):

```
from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable
print CreateTable(Customer.__table__).compile(engine)
```

Comment: Looks like it can't handle LONGTEXT type. :(  
`CompileError: (in table 'source', column 'html_source'): Compiler <sqlalchemy.sql.compiler.GenericTypeCompiler object at 0x7f8c1cf97cd0> can't render element of type <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql.base.LONGTEXT'>
`

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck It should. If you compile with your specific engine it should use a MySQL-specific compiler instead of `GenericTypeCompiler`, I believe.\

Comment: Ah! `from sqlalchemy import create_engine`  

`mysql_engine = create_engine('mysql://')`
`from sqlalchemy.schema import CreateTable`
`print CreateTable(Customer.__table__).compile(mysql_engine)`